# Objective-C dynamic implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

**Description + sample + explanation:** (You can skip to the question section)

I'd like to make an object instance, which can be implemented by different implementations, depend on a condition (the internet status).

Simple declaration

```
@interface LoginController : NSObject

/** The currently logged-in User. Nil if not logged-in yet. */
@property (strong, nonatomic) User *currentUser;

// Singleton object
+ (instancetype)shareInstance;

/** Abstract methods, will do nothing if call directly. Use inheritance implements (Online/Offline) instead. */
- (User *)loginByEmail:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)pwd;

@end

@interface LoginControllerOnline : LoginController
// Login will call request to server.
@end

@interface LoginControllerOffline : LoginController
// Login will check data in coredata.
@end
```

The LoginController's login method actually do nothing (`return nil`). Instead, the inherited class (Online/Offline) overwrite the parent login's method, with different implementations (as in comments)

And then, I have a manager to define which class should be in use:

```
@implement InternetManager

+ (LoginController *)loginController
{
    return [self hasInternet] ? [LoginControllerOnline shareInstance] : [LoginControllerOffline shareInstance];
}

+ (BOOL)hasInternet
{
    // Check with Reachability.
}

@end
```

This work. But it's not the mechanism I'd like to achieve.

1. This mean I have 2 instances of inherited LoginController instead of 1.
2. When `internetStatus` change from `offline` to `online`, I'd like to re-login online (to get session/oauthToken...). But, I'll have to do many things (copy user, change instance, check retained...) before I can actually call from login online

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way for me to create only one instance of `LoginController`, which hold the same properties (`User`), but can has different (dynamic) implementations (Online/Offline)?

**Update question:**

Quote from Apple's [Dynamic typing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DynamicTyping.html):

> The isa Pointer:
>
> Every object has an isa instance variable that
>   identifies the object's class. The runtime uses this pointer to
>   determine the actual class of the object when it needs to.

So, is there a way for me to change this `isa pointer` of an object instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the real problem is that you've given these things direct primary ownership of state that you actually don't want them to own — factor it out. There's no copying, just give each an instance of the thing that marshals sate at `-init` and allow them to talk to it.

Then just do the normal programming thing when you want to do either one thing or another based on a condition: use an `if` statement.

So, I don't think use of the dynamic runtime is appropriate. However, academically, supposing an interest:

If you really must, use `object_setClass`, which "[s]ets the class of an object", answering your actual question. Obviously you need the storage to be compatible, so probably your subclasses shouldn't declare any properties or instance variables.

A commonly-discussed alternative for this general area is not changing the class of an existing instance but changing the methods that are a member of the class. So you'd have two alternative implementations of `-loginByEmail:password:` and set which was the one that actually responded to that selector dynamically. But there's really no advantage over just using an `if` if you have access to the source code and a bunch of disadvantages around its generally indirect, opaque nature. The whole thing is usually known as swizzling. `class_replaceMethod` is the key component but just search for swizzling.